# Failing when converting a PKL (Stylegan2-ada) to PT (Pytorch model)

Tags: python, model

I have a problem.

When I try to convert my pkl model to a pt model, I get this error.

```
  File "/content/stylegan2-pytorch/convert_weight.py", line 221, in <module>
    generator, discriminator, g_ema = pickle.load(f)
  File "./stylegan2/dnnlib/tflib/network.py", line 278, in __setstate__
    assert state["version"] in [2, 3, 4]
AssertionError
```

I do not know what to do and how I can convert my model succesfully.
Can someone please help me? I'd really appreciate that!

Answer (score -1):

The newest file `network.py` has contained more `state["version"]` (`[2, 3, 4, 5]`), you only need to find the new edition of `stylegan2-ada`.

Comment: Answer needs rephrasing, current version is hardly understandable.